# How to recursively delete all files in folder that dont match a given pattern

Tags: linux

I would like to delete all files in a given folder that dont match the pattern `^transactions_[0-9]+`

Let's say I have these files in the folder

```
file_list
transactions_010116.csv
transactions_020116.csv
transactions_check_010116.csv
transactions_check_020116.csv
```

I would like to delete `transactions_check_010116.csv` and `transactions_check_020116.csv` and leave the first two as they are using `^transactions_[0-9]+`

I've been trying to use `find` something like below, but this expression deletes everything in the folder not just the files that dont match the pattern:

```
find /my_file_location -type f ! -regex '^transactions_[0-9]+' -delete
```

What i'm trying to do here is using regex find all files in folder that dont start with `^transactions_[0-9]+` and delete them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your implementation, you could have to use option -E to allow the use of full regexes. An other problem is that `-regex` gives you an almost full path starting with the directory you passed.

So the correct command should be:

```
 find -E /my_file_location ! -regex '.*/transactions_[0-9]+$' -type f -delete
```

But you should first issue the same with `-print` to be sure...

Comment: thanks for your reply, unfortunately it returns `find: unknown predicate -E'` - is there another way to use regex expressions with a find command? I tried find `/my_file_location -regextype sed ! -regex ".*/transactions_[0-9]\+" -type f -delete` but this didn't find the pattern and so deleted everything in the folder

Comment: @SamGilbert: does this `find /my_file_location ! -regex '.*/transactions_[0-9]+$' -type f -print` lists the files you want to delete? And as I have not the same `find`as you what can you pass to `-regextype`?

Comment: ah I got it, the pattern `'.*/transactions_[0-9]+.*'` prints the required files! So now able to delete them, thanks for your help

Comment: This is the solution I went with > `find /my_file_location ! -regex '.*/transactions_[0-9]+.*' -type f -delete`

Answer (score 1):

**grep** has -v option to grep everything not matching the provided regex:

```
find . | grep -v '^transactions_[0-9]+'  | xargs rm -f
```

Comment: thanks for the quick reply, I've tested the solution you recommended > `find /my_file_location | grep -v 'transactions_[0-9]\+' | xargs rm -f`
I had to escape the `+`, but I think it's nearly there. Only issue is that it is also trying to remove the directory, can it be adjusted to just remove files?

Comment: I tried this > `find -type f /my_file_location | grep -v 'transactions_[0-9]\+' | xargs rm -f` but errors with `paths must precede expressions`, putting it after the file path brings a `grep: invalid  -- 't'` - any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: I was suggesting:

`find -type f /my_file_location | grep 'transactions_[0-9]\+' | xargs rm -f`